# How to animate for a 2D ios game?

Tags: ios, animation, 2d

I'm planning on making a simple 2D game (I'm leaning towards an endless runner) for the iPhone and am using cocos2d and I can make stand alone images in Photoshop or Illustrator but I'm not sure what the best way to animate them is??

I don't know if I should animate a character running in flash then save each frame as a png and then use something like texture packer to make a sprite sheet or loop the png's together in cocos2d?? I don't know what works well with cocos2d and how to optimize the animation to run smoothly and reduce memory. I'm aware it maybe a broad question but any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should use sprite sheet and animate the frames using cocos2d.

1. [Here are the tutorials by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/cocos2d)
2. [Here is the official coco2d video tutorial and sample](http://cocos2d.org/doc.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the help these links should help

Answer (score 0):

[Plenty of tutorials out there.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) Your question is probably going to be flagged and closed in the near future. Try googling your questions first next time.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help and the advice, I had a rough idea of what to do, doing research on the internet you find so many ways to do something, I just wanted some conformation and other advice from potential experts that I was going in the right direction.